# Graphiql (GraphQL UI) not loading in Chrome but works in Firefox and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, graphql, graphiql, absinthe

I'm not sure what changed in Chrome but the Graphiql GUI tool is not loading.

[image]

In Firefox and Safari it works just fine. I have disabled all Chrome extensions, restarted Chrome, and restarted my Mac. The error persists. How do I debug this?

In graphql-workspace.min.js it errors on:

```
this.state.config.state.proxy || this.state.config.state.headers.forEach(function(e) {
```

Error:

```
graphiql-workspace.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at t.value (graphiql-workspace.min.js:1)
    at t.value (graphiql-workspace.min.js:1)
    at t.value (graphiql-workspace.min.js:1)
    at t.value (graphiql-workspace.min.js:1)
    at performInitialMount (react-dom.min.js:13)
    at p.mountComponent (react-dom.min.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.min.js:14)
    at mountChildren (react-dom.min.js:14)
    at m._createInitialChildren (react-dom.min.js:13)
    at mountComponent (react-dom.min.js:13)
```

Here is a picture of it working in Firefox:
[image]

Not sure why `headers` is undefined.

I am using:
Elixir, Phoenix, Absinthe, Absinth-Plug, Vue, Vue-Apollo, apollo-boost, graphql,

Since the GUI appears to be loading from a CDN I'm wondering if that's a direction I should explore. However the network tab in chrome shows no failures.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that much of the activity/history of using Graphiql is saved to localStorage. I'm not sure what broke the history but I inspected the broken config in the console with a few breakpoints. This lead me to discover that localStorage was being used. I then cleared a lot of key/values in there and my Graphiql rendered successfully.